# VIM: Replace [aeiou]' with the respective accented letter -- with an exception

Tags: vim

Whenever the letter aiouAIOU are followed by the symbol ', I would like to instruct VIM to automatically replace the letters with the accented letters àìòùÀÌÒÙ (while removing the ').

The letter "e" (and E) is however an exception: if preceded by a space or a CR and followed by ', becomes è (and È; while removing the '), otherwise becomes é.

This does not capture completely the rules of the Italian language, but it is a start for me.

I am currently using this in my .vimrc

`nnoremap <leader>, :%s/\([aeiouAEIOU]\)'/\=tr(submatch(1), 'aeiouAEIOU', 'àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ')/g<CR>`

how should I extend it to perform the conditional replacement I am looking for, in one shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to type the upper case `é` .. so I just use `x` and `X` for them. This cmd should help:

```
%s/\v(\s|\_^)([eE])'/\=tr(submatch(2),'eE','èÈ')/g|%s/\v([aeiouAEIOU])'/\=tr(submatch(1), 'aeiouAEIOU', 'àxìòùÀXÌÒÙ')/g
```

You can use it in your mapping as well.

Comment: Not sure it works: it does NOT remove the ' for the isolated letters. But thank you immensely: it is a starting point for me.

Comment: @Michele Oh, I didn't notice the quote problem, I updated the answer, now it should work. again, you should replace the `x and X` with the right characters.

Comment: It still does not work. 

 -VIM complains (as I add it in .vimrc) that 
  ```\ should be followed by /, ? or &```.

 - [eE]’ preceded by a space are replaced and the ‘ is removed, but the space is not retained


I see you have created several search&replace command in VIM, using regular expressions…
I am trying to learn, from your competent help, VIM regex but I am still very unfamiliar with them.

Comment: @Michele it worked here. regarding the "space", I don't know what do you expect. it is always a good way to paste "before" and "after" example, so that we can know what are you expecting exactly.